# How can I fix a loading screen crash in Grand Theft Auto IV?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-iv

I have a copy of *Grand Theft Auto IV* on Steam. When I start it, everything is fine: it loads and I can press "Play". However, the game crashes straight to the desktop—without any error message—about 5 seconds after the loading screen comes up.

I've tried reinstalling the game, redownloading the game, deleting all mods, and trying to find all the original files from the game on Steam, but nothing's worked.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Re-install, Re-Download, delete all mods and trying to find the original files from Gta IV Steam. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Mark, you don't have any idea's?

Comment: verify game file cache? I had problems running on Windows 7, and had to creat some kind of shortcut to one of the exe. Run it in XP compatility, and ensure that community rubbish was also running.

Comment: @Doomsknight Could you tell me the steps how to do that? Thank you alot!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend verifying the game cache.. Its possible you are missing files.

To verify cache, right click the steam game in the list, properties, Local files tab and find the verify cache button. Click it and wait till it finishes.

It will download any corrupted/missing files.

As for the other stuff, it was too long ago to remember.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try this (from the [PC Gaming Wiki, GTA IV article](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/GTA_IV#Game_Fails_to_start)):

> There is an issue in which the Steam Version of the game (And possibly
>   non-steam) will fail to start. The Rockstar Social club login pops up,
>   but after you sign in, or go offline, the game fails to start. This is
>   caused by an out of date Games for Windows Live Client. You can
>   download the client [here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient). You may have to start run this program each
>   time you want to play.
>
> Unfortunately, however, updating the client may not be the only issue
>   preventing you from logging in to Games for Windows Live. It could
>   also be a problem with your MTU size. To determine what your MTU size
>   is, open a cmd window (click Start, type cmd, press enter). Once in
>   the cmd window, enter the following command:
>
> `C:\>netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`
>
> This will show you the MTU size currently set for all of your network
>   interfaces. For your account to be able to log in, the MTU size must
>   be set to 1500. If it is not, a quick fix is to just force the change
>   in with:
>
> `C:\>netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "Local Area Connection"
>   mtu=1500 store=persistent`
>
> Assuming, of course, that "Local Area Connection" is the name of your
>   network interface. Note that even though we set "store=persistent",
>   this change will not be permanent and will be lost on reboot.
>
> If the game loads as a process under Task Manager, but disappears
>   after a while, run GTAIV.exe under compatibility mode for Windows XP
>   SP3 or higher. In Windows 7, this can be found under the Programs tab
>   of the Control Panel.

I'd also try installing [XLiveLess](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto_IV#XLiveLess), if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Delete all of your save files.

Comment: Severely lacking any useful details.  I know in many of the games I play, you can hit [ESC] and make the load screen go away and see what is happening behind the screen.. Does this game offer a way to so something similar perhaps?